# Equivariant cohomology with discrete group action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

As far as I know, the equivariant cohomology can be regarded as the generalisation of de Rham cohomology with group action on manifolds. From the literature, the group action is Lie group type. I am wondering whether there is a generalization of equivariant cohomology to the case of discrete group.

One example I am interested in is the square torus with 90 degree rotation. How can I consider the discrete equivariant cohomology?

Comment: Countable discrete groups are 0-dimensional Lie groups. Do you have more exotic discrete groups in mind?

Comment: To clarify the previous comment: if the literature covers continuous Lie group actions, then it covers discrete group actions as a special case.

Comment: The continuous isometry can be described in terms of Lie group via the Killing vectors. And this can be used to construct equivariant differential form. For discrete isometry, I don't see an obvious generalization....